# Is it good to use Irish Moss

Tags: carbonation, stuck-fermentation

Is it good to use Irish moss, if I'm using a beer kit to brew beer. The research I've done says I should add it to last 10 minutes of the boil. Does anyone know any different.

Comment: To be more clear: Irish moss is a fining. It is used to remove proteins (hot break) in the beer which can render the beer hazy. If the beer kit only requires that hot water is added and no boiling is needed, then the extract has already been boiled, and the proteins which would be removed by using Irish moss have already been removed. I suppose (can anyone confirm this?) that other LME will also have been boiled to hot break, so that addition of Irish Moss will not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of beer kit being used. Some are based on malt extract and some are based on grains.

If the kit is "all grain" based then the Irish Moss can be added as recommended above/elsewhere.

*However*, beer "kits" are usually based on canned malt extract, although some kits provide dried malt extract. If that is the case then the use of Irish moss or protofloc/etc is IMHO *not* required. The "mashing" operation has been done at the factory and the brew will clear well on its own. I might add that if the kit is a canned extract kit then IMHO boiling is not required at all.

Comment: Why do you say "no boiling is required" for extract worts? How would the wort be sterilized without boiling?

Comment: @GrainMother extract is boiled when it is canned - so it arrives sterile. However one can "re-pasteurise" it by dissolving the extract in sufficient, boiling (or just boiled) water when making up the wort.

Answer (score 0):

Irish moss / whirlflocs go in the last few minutes of the boil.

However, they do little to benifiet a beer unless you whirlpool and leave it behind.

All too often I see homebrewers use these finings and transfer them to the fermentor and waste beer in fluffed up trub.

Comment: Does Irish Moss (or "protofloc") have any effect on final clarity when boiling wort made from extract?